# How to change the format of datepicker input from 13/7/2018 to 13-07-2018 in tornadofx?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

[image: Current output of datepicker.]

Cannot set the input format of datepicker. I want to change it to dd-LL-yyyy.

Comment: Well, I never worked with tornadofx, but the DatePicker has a `setFormat` method (https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-controls/blob/master/src/main/java/tornadofx/control/DateTimePicker.java#L100). If this does not solve your problem, please update your question accordingly and what the error messages/problems are

Comment: You have referred datetimepicker but I am using datepicker where I cant find any set format method

Comment: You're right, missed that. According to [this documentation](https://tornadofx.io/dokka/tornadofx/tornadofx/javafx.scene.control.-date-picker/index.html) the DatePicker in tornadofx extends/is the javafx DatePicker, which has a `converter` to convert date to string and vice versa: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html#converterProperty

Comment: yes, have to use `setConverter()` method. Problem solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Tornadofx `datepicker()` basically uses java class `DatePicker`located in *javafx.scene.control.DatePicker.java*. `DatePicker`  extends from `ComboBoxBase<java.time.LocalDate>`
and so the value is always a type of `LocalDate` .

To change the format there is a method defined in class `DatePicker` named `setConverter()` which takes argument typed `StringConverter<LocalDate>`. This can be done using `LocalDateStringConverter()` method defined in *javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter.java* . It basically takes two arguments to get funtional and both are type of `DateTimeFormatter`, the 1st argument is for formatting and 2nd for parsing. Here to achive my goal I have seen that one formatter is enough to get desired output.

`DateTimeFormatter` is a class defined in *java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.java* which is a formatter for printing and parsing date-time objects. `ofPattern()` method defined in it takes string pattern like `"dd-MM-yyyy"` ,which is my desired one here. So we can do `val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")`

Now we can apply `setConverter(LocalDateStringConverter(dateFormatter, dateFormatter))` which is a call to "*java get set method*" or we can use "*Kotlin synthetic properties*" like `converter = LocalDateStringConverter(dateFormatter, dateFormatter)`, which is preferable.

An working snippet is given :

```
datepicker() {
                 ...

                 val pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy"
                 val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)
                 converter = LocalDateStringConverter(dateFormatter, dateFormatter)
              }
```

Output snapshot:

[image: output of formatted date-picker]

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: @petezurich added explanation.